# Is there a way in elasticsearch to automatically remove an index from an alias without deleting it

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch cluster is as follows:
my_policy:

```
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_docs": 100000,
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my_template:

```
{
  "index_patterns": ["1_events_data*"], 
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy",
    "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "1_events_data" 
  }
}
```

and the first index, 1_events_data-000001:

```
{
  "aliases": {
    "1_events_data":{
      "is_write_index": true 
    }
  }
}
```

The alias 1_events_data is serving for reading and writing data. i want to automatically remove old indexes from the alias so when i query the alias i wont get the old indexed data, without deleting the index. i know i can add a delete phase in the policy but as i said, i dont want to delete the index, i only want to make it unqueriable. is there any way to do this?

Comment: How are you determining your data is old? If there is a timestamp, you can use an alias filter to make sure you only get data that is `now-30d` or something: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered

Comment: This is an interesting approach. i do have a timestamp on the data. but what i understand about alias filtering is that it will still query the data (inspite that it wont return anything), and i don't want that to happen.

Comment: If you don't want the data queried, just remove it